# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'abc' to data type int in nopcommerce 4.3

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, nopcommerce, sqlexception

I want to search **GTIN** option in admin product list. So, for that I am providing GTIN value in **ProductLoadAllPaged** store procedure. Now, when I search GTIN value from product list at that time throw datatable error and from console application get message that

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'abc' to data type int.**

Here is store procedure added code,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductLoadAllPaged]
(
    @GTIN nvarchar(50) --AWAZ
)
AS
BEGIN
    .....
    
    --filter by vendor
    IF @VendorId > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.VendorId = ' + CAST(@VendorId AS nvarchar(max))
    END
    
    --AWAZ
    IF @GTIN is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.Gtin = ' +  @GTIN             
    END

    --filter by warehouse
    IF @WarehouseId > 0
    BEGIN
        --we should also ensure that 'ManageInventoryMethodId' is set to 'ManageStock' (1)
        --but we skip it in order to prevent hard-coded values (e.g. 1) and for better performance
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND  
            (
                (p.UseMultipleWarehouses = 0 AND
                    p.WarehouseId = ' + CAST(@WarehouseId AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                OR
                (p.UseMultipleWarehouses > 0 AND
                    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ProductWarehouseInventory [pwi]
                    WHERE [pwi].WarehouseId = ' + CAST(@WarehouseId AS nvarchar(max)) + ' AND [pwi].ProductId = p.Id))
            )'
    END
    
    .....
END
```

Comment: you need to  put @GTIN in quotes to be considered as  character  change `AND p.Gtin = ' +  @GTIN` to AND p.Gtin = '' +  @GTIN  + ''''

Comment: do you know in which of the columns or parameter the value "abc" is stored? You Check if "VendorID" and later if "WarehouseID" is greater than 0. To do this comparison SQL needs to convert "VendorID"/ "WarehouseID" to the datatype integer. The rest of your procedure doesn't seem to cause this error, IMHO.

Comment: @MathiasFogel in GTIN "abc" is store. Else there is no connection with vendorid and warehouseid, that I display because you can know that between vendorid and warehouseid I added the code.

Comment: @eshirvana I used your code, and its filtering also but showing empty data, while the data is having.

Comment: @s.k.Soni are you sure ?, I'm guessing you need to use `like`

Comment: why don't you cast GTIN as you do it with the other parameters? Like: + CAST(@GTIN AS nvarchar(max)) +

Comment: @MathiasFogel I tried but didnt work.

Comment: @eshirvana can you show syntax with my GTIN code?

Comment: @MathiasFogel If I do your code then its showing error i.e. : Must declare the scalar variable "@GTIN"

Comment: Are you executing the procedure like this: Exec [dbo].[ProductLoadAllPaged] @GTIN='abc' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so seems like you need to chnage this part of code :

```
   --AWAZ
    IF @GTIN is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.Gtin like ''%' + @GTIN + '%'''            
    END
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank You So Much For The Help. :)